# PerlNET and ExcelDNA

Tags: excel-2007, excel-dna

Content: Office 2007, ExcelDNA 0.30, ActiveState Perl SDK 3.0, PerlNET

I'm trying to use PerlNET to write an ExcelDNA add-in. The idea is to write something that can handle a variable number of parameters, like =SUM().

The Perl code:

```perl
#!perl
package AddIn; 

use strict;
use diagnostics; 
use namespace "System";
use PerlNET qw(AUTOCALL);
=for interface
    [interface: pure]
    static double PNSUM(double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
    static double PNSUM(double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double,double);
=cut

sub new {
    my($package) = @_;
    my $self = bless {} => $package;
    return $self;
}

sub PNSUM {
    my $result = 0.0;
    foreach (@_) {
        $result += $_;
    }
    return $result;
}
#~ print SUM(1.9,2.8,3.7,4.6,5.5,6.4,7.3,8.2,9.1);
```

The DNA code

```
<DnaLibrary Name="Perl NET Demo" RuntimeVersion="v2.0">
  <ExternalLibrary Path="BOPN.DLL" />
</DnaLibrary>
```

The .XLL file loads okay, but PNSUM() is not visible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is some discussion on ParamArrays with Excel-DNA here: http://exceldna.codeplex.com/discussions/406719.

Comment: @Govert: Thanks for pointing out to me my previous posting on your Wiki ;)

Comment: I also hope the link might be of value to others who run into this question...